# Google Sheet connect with database

Tags: mysql, database, excel, r-googlesheets

I have a very big file in google sheet with many records, rows and columns.

I want to make a database from this. Can I, in some way, personalize the display? I want to reference row to field and search by name.

Is there some software of access to achieve this?

Picture of sheet

[image]

Picture of database

[image]

Comment: As a mean person (like I am): Just do not use google sheets. Get a proper office which supports stuff like that by default. (excel/access) :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question but from what i gather you wish to take your google sheet and import it into a mysql database?

If so, I'd take a look at "Navicat" its a program that will let you import an xls or csv into a mysql DB (you can export the google sheet to xls)

They have a trial version here: https://www.navicat.com/de/download/navicat-premium

Comment: Thanks Mark, but I want something like here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/JYEzJ.png

Some ideas?

Comment: I recommend [Excel2MySQL](http://excel2mysql.net)... then to create what you want .. you need to create an application that interprets your data from the MySQL table and create a user interface like your diagram.  I recommend Python + PyQt4, however if you've never done that... you will need developer experience and time for learning curve.  PHP and HTML is another option.  There are many choices, but they all require programming experience.  Good Luck.